# Extracting elements of an array in bash

Tags: bash

I have an array `a = ( 1 2 3 4 5 6)`
Now I want to extract 1 and 2nd elements of the array into two different variables and assign rest of the elements of array `a` to another array that will have elements only 3rd element onwards .
so that b and c are the variables with 1st and second variable respectively

just as :

```
b=$a[0];
c=$a[1];
```

and

```
arr=( 3 4 5 6 )`
```

Comment: BTW, in the real world, if in a function context or somewhere else it wasn't important to preserve the values in `"$@"`, I might implement this with `set -- "${a[@]}"; b=$1; shift; c=$1; shift; arr=( "$@" )`.

Comment: It helps to switch from asking "When do I need braces?" to "When can I *omit* braces?" The answer to the second question is far shorter ("when the expansion is *just* a variable name that isn't followed by a valid identifier character") than the answer to the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$a[0]` doesn't treat `[0]` as part of the expansion -- rather, it's a separate string to be appended. As given in [the bash-hackers' wiki page on paramater expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), you need to use curly braces to surround subscripts when extracting content from an array.

---

```
a=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 )
b=${a[0]}
c=${a[1]}
arr=( "${a[@]:2}" )

declare -p b c arr # print definitions of variables b, c, and arr
```

...properly emits:

```
declare -- b="1"
declare -- c="2"
declare -a arr='([0]="3" [1]="4" [2]="5" [3]="6")'
```

Comment: Does  `arr=( "${a[@]:2}" )` mean starting from 2nd element to the end of the array ?

Comment: Exactly; it's the array version of the `${PARAMETER:OFFSET:LENGTH}` syntax described in the included link, also covered at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays